# How do I find out which command name is bound to a particular key sequence in VSCode and vice-versa?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Are there commands equivalent to Emacs' `C-h k` and `C-h w`?

If not, is there at least a big file containing **all** keybindings I can search through?

Edit: the "vice-versa" is trivial if you know the command name. Just type it in the command prompt and it shows the associated keybinding. I'm more interested in the former.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find command by pressing keybinding in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303216/how-to-find-command-by-pressing-keybinding-in-vscode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the keyboard shortcuts editor (cmd+k cmd+s), and you can search for keybindings to see what they're bound to. e.g. search `cmd+s` and "Save" will be returned.

You can also click the keybindings.json link on that page to see all the keybindings in json form.

Answer (score 5):

v1.28.0 added a better way to search for bound key chords, see [search keyboard shortcuts: release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_record-and-search-keyboard-shortcuts).

> Record and search keyboard 
>   shortcuts
>
> In the Keyboard Shortcuts editor (Ctrl+K Ctrl+S), you can now search
>   for keybindings just by typing keystrokes instead of typing out the
>   key name (example 'shift'). Turn on the Recording Keys mode and type
>   the keystrokes you want to search for.
>
> You can also enter into the Recording Keys mode using Alt+K. Press the
>   Esc key to exit from Recording Keys mode

.

Comment: The actual page specify : "You can also enter into the Recording Keys mode using ⌥⌘K. Press the Esc key to exit from Recording Keys mode." (the shortcut is quite different)

Comment: How does this get down-voted recently - unless it is a bad actor.  Duper?

Answer (score 2):

**A) Help -> Keyboard Shortcuts Reference**

It will open a PDF with a table containing "hotkey - command" pairs, categorized. (On Windows, it will open [this PDF](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf).)

**B) File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts**

This will open the [keyboard shortucts editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor) where you can search for the command or even the keys.