# How to find command by pressing keybinding in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I'm looking for a way for VS Code to tell me the command name for a keybinding.

In Emacs, this functionality is available under `describe-key` (`C-h k`).

For example, in VS Code <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> maps to `editor.action.selectAll`. So ideally I'd press a keyboard shortcut, then <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, then VS Code would tell me `editor.action.selectAll`.

As a partial solution, I can open my `keybindings.json` and search for <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>, but this doesn't work for extensions. (My particular use case is figuring out what the Vim `o` command is called so I can remap it.)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning "C-h k", that's how I found this question ;-)

Comment: I'm removing the "emacs" tag, since this is a question about Microsoft's VS Code editor. The OP mentions Emacs as a point of comparison only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can find the command associated with a key binding by typing the keybinding into the `Keyboard Shortcuts` search box:

[image: keyboard shortcuts]

Unfortunately, [per the source code](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/762eb011f1ce2e872ec064bfaf28e479b99d0613/src/actions/commands/actions.ts#L2717-L2755), the vim extension doesn't use this mechanism to bind the <kbd>o</kbd> key.

Fortunately, it does let you [rebind the keys in settings](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim#user-content-key-remapping). First, open settings (<kbd>F1</kbd> `Preferences: Open Settings`), then add (to bind <kbd>i</kbd>, for example):

```
"vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    "before": ["i"],
    "after": ["o"]
],
```

If you have the new settings UI, you might need to search for `vim.normalModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive` first, and then click `Edit in settings.json`.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287561/how-do-i-find-out-which-command-name-is-bound-to-a-particular-key-sequence-in-vs/52709734#52709734 for an improvement to searching for bound keystrokes and commands.

Answer (score 8):

As of the September 2018 release, [VSCode can do this from the keyboard shortcuts window](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_record-and-search-keyboard-shortcuts).

[image: Screenshot of keyboard shortcuts pane with recording keys active]

From the keyboard shortcuts window (cmd+k cmd+s), type cmd+option+k or click the keyboard icon on the right.

Kudos to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303216/how-to-find-command-by-pressing-keybinding-in-vscode/53089256?noredirect=1#comment92345682_52394941) linking to this approach as an answer to another question.

Comment: This is a duplicate answer - see my comment above.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to have this as an answer and didn't know the etiquette in this case. I can remove this answer though I do feel the updated screenshot provides value. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I would do two things in your answer: explicitly reference the comment above and then upvote that actual answer on the commented link since you did find it helpful.  Neither of these is required of course, I just think it is the nicest way to handle it.